# Get a class name by knowing part of it's name when it's not the only class applied to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm looking for a way using jquery/javascript to get a class name when I only know part of it and there are more than one classes applied to that element.

So if I'm looking for a class that I know starts with "charLimit_" I want to know that full class name even when it's not the only class applied to a given element.
Example HTML would be.

```
<input class="charLimit_30 lastNameValidation" type="text" />
```

What I have so far below will put both "charLimit_30" and "lastNameValidation" into an array, but how do I then say I only want "charLimit_30" and then only tell me the value found after the underscore (30).

```
var classMName = $('[class*=charLimit_]').attr("class").split(' ');
```

Thanks in advance for you help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kinda like what inkedmn said, but in a more jQuery-ish way:

```
var numbersAfterCharLimit = [];

$('[class*="charLimit_"]').each(function() {
    var matches;
    if (matches = this.className.match(/(?:\s+|^)charLimit_([0-9]+)(?:\s+|$)/)) {
        numbersAfterCharLimit.push(parseInt(matches[1], 10));
    }
});
```

Comment: Nope, can't use /\b/ there : )

Comment: And if you're already using `parseInt`, I would advice to supply `radix` (i.e. `10`). You don't want to end up translating '08' into '0'.

Comment: @nickf, because class values are delimited with whitespaces, and your boundary will match "foo" in "foo-bar baz", although it shouldn't. It's a pretty common mistake. I've seen dozens of `hasClassName` implementations where people fall into this trap and use `"\b" + className + "\b"` instead of a proper - `(?:\\s+|^)` + className + (?:\\s+|$)`.

Comment: i realised the mistake (that it'd match `-`) just after I commented, but I'm glad I waited for your response! Thanks for the great advice!

Comment: hey guys, thanks for the help.  I'm working with the latest revised code here and I cannot get it to enter the "if" statement if the class looks something like this class="dogs charLimit_20 cats" or in other words if there are 1 or more classes surrounding the "charLimit" class.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hey Vine, i've fixed two bugs in that code again (you can't do `if (var matches = ...)` and i had double-slashed the `\s` when I didn't need to. That should work now.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need first occurrence and everything that follows underscore in class is a number, then something like this would do it:

```
$('[class*=charLimit_]').attr("class").match(/(?:\s|^)charLimit_(\d+)/)[1];
```

Comment: Correct and simple, but the jQuery style guide eschews "match" in favor of "test" and "exec." See http://docs.jquery.com/JQuery_Core_Style_Guidelines

Comment: @Gaius Interesting. I suppose `exec` could be slightly faster in this case.

Comment: This answer works perfectly for me if you remove the [0] after the attr("class").

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that `attr` returns a string, not an array :) Thanks, I changed answer appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work (at least on stackoverflow):

```
var test = $('[class*=owner]').attr('class').split(' ');
for(i in test){
    if(test[i].indexOf('post-sign') !== false){
        test = test[i].split('-');
        // replace this with a return
        console.log(test[1]);
        break;
    }
}
```

And one that will work with the code that he is trying to do it with:

```
var test = $('[class*=charLimit_]').attr('class').split(' ');
for(i in test){
    if(test[i].indexOf('charLimit_') !== false){
        test = test[i].split('_');
        // replace this with a return if it is in a function
        console.log(test[1]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: It returns the word 'sign'... equivalent to the '30' in his question.

Comment: "tell me the value found after the underscore (30)."

Answer (score 0):

```
var classes = $('input').attr('class');
var myNum = '';
for(var i=0;i<classes.length;i++){
    if(classes[i].match(/^charLimit_.*$/){
        myNum = classes[i].split('_')[1];
    }
}
```

Something like that would work, unless of course there's some jQuery magic way of doing it that I'm simply unaware of :)

Comment: This would end up with myNum = "30 lastNameValidation"... I tried out your script and you're missing a ")" after the match. Also the classes variable ends up as a string and not an array.

Comment: Would that do it: classes[i].match(/^charLimit_(\\d+)(\\s+)/) ? (Not so good at regex)